# Inheriting from a form c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

everybody. My plan is to create a separate class, in which I would declare all the labels and textbox values. But to do so I have to inherit from a form. The problem is that when I inherit from a form my class becomes a form and calls elements from itself. Setting the properties of labels and textboxes to public did not help. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment2v3
{
class Declarations : Form1
{
    public List<Label> ErrRep
    { get; set; }
    public List<TextBox> TextBoxes
    { get; set; }
    public List<ComboBox> ComboBoxes
    { get; set; }
    public Declarations()
    {
        ErrRep = DeclareErrorReports();
        TextBoxes = DeclareTextBoxes();
        ComboBoxes = DeclareComboBoxes();
    }
    List<Label> DeclareErrorReports()
    {
        var ER = new List<Label>();
        ER.Add(errorReport1);
        ER.Add(errorReport2);
        ER.Add(errorReport3);
        return ER;
    }//Would be used if try catch worked
    List<TextBox> DeclareTextBoxes()
    {
        List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
        TextBoxes.Add(textBoxPizza1);
        TextBoxes.Add(textBoxPizza2);
        TextBoxes.Add(textBoxPizza3);
        return TextBoxes;
    }//Puts all textBoxes into a list
    List<ComboBox> DeclareComboBoxes()
    {
        var ComboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>();
        ComboBoxes.Add(comboBoxPizza1);
        ComboBoxes.Add(comboBoxPizza2);
        ComboBoxes.Add(comboBoxPizza3);
        return ComboBoxes;
    }//Puts all comboboxes into a list
     // ^ Boring declarations
}
}
```

[image: Form design]

Comment: what do you mean by this: The problem is that when I inherit from a form my class becomes a form and calls elements from itself.

Comment: Look right on the screenshot. Declarations.cs becomes a form. It even has a design option like a normal windows form

Comment: well that is how inheritance works. If that is not what you want, then reword your question and tell us what you want to accomplish and someone can tell you how. The whole point of inheritance is: I need everything the base class has plus I am going to add more.

Comment: Ok. I want to be able to get labels and textboxes to another class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably inherit from UserControl instead. With your own UserControl, you can add it to one or more forms in one or more places.

There are plenty of tutorials out there which guide you in creating your own WinForms UserControl.

Comment: Will look into that. Thanks